# Multiplication operator in Gaussian Sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

Consider the Gaussian Sobolev space $W^{p,r}(\gamma_n)$. It is the completion of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with respect to the norm
$$
\|f\|_{s,p}=\sum_{|\alpha|=0}^r\|\partial^\alpha f\|_p,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the $p$-norm with respect to the standard Gaussian measure $\gamma_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Equivalently, it consists of all $f\in L^2(\gamma_n)$ such that the distributional derivatives up to order $s$ are regular and in $L^p(\gamma_n)$.

Does the operator $T\colon f\mapsto xf$ map $W^{1,2}(\gamma_1)$ or even $L^2(\gamma_1)$ into $L^2(\gamma_1)$?
If so, is it continuous as an operator from the respective domain to $L^2(\gamma_1)$?

Comment: A multiplication operator maps $L^2(\mu)$ into $L^2(\mu)$ if and only if the function you multiply with is $\mu$-essentially bounded. This is clearly not the case for  $x\mapsto x$. Also, if $T$ maps $W^{1,2}(\gamma_1)$ into $L^2(\gamma_1)$, it is continuous by the closed graph theorem. I cannot answer the remaining part of the question right now.

Comment: Thank you. I did not expect it to map $L^2(\gamma_1)$ into itself, and the reason you give seems obvious now. However I don't see why $\text{Graph}(T)$ is closed if $T\colon W^{1,2}(\gamma_1)\to L^2(\gamma_1)$.

Comment: @johnny10: Suppose $f_n \to f$ in $W^{1,2}$ and $T f_n \to g$.  In particular $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$ and so a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ a.e.  Then $T f_{n_k} = x f_{n_k}$ converges to $xf$ a.e., yet $T f_{n_k} \to g$ in $L^2$, so $g = xf$ a.e.  This shows $T$ has closed graph.

Comment: The good old subsequence argument, should have thought of that, thank you. However it is still not clear if $T$ even maps between these two spaces.